# itms or itms-apps links no longer open AppStore?

Tags: ios, swift

I used to have a `UIButton` that would load an `URL` in the form of **itms://example.com** this when pressed would load the relevant item within the `AppStore` application on `iOS` (rather than in the browser).

However that is no longer working for me. If I switch the URL to https:// then the relevant page opens in the browser but if I use itms or itms-apps then it does nothing. Any ideas why or if there’s a new way of doing this?

The use case is to refer people from one app to download another from the AppStore.

Comment: You should use `SKStoreProductViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the http link should open directly into App Store app via universal links.

```
// open Google Earth in the app store
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-earth/id293622097?mt=8")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

If you wish to keep the experience inside of your app, then use `SKStoreProductViewController` as pointed out by **rmaddy**

Comment: So using the http option (at least while testing) does not open the link in the AppStore. It opens it in safari. Also I don’t want to manage this in my own app. I want a link that opens in the AppStore app like it used to with the itms link.

Comment: Hmm, what version of iOS/device are you testing on? Does the code posted above not open the AppStore for you?

Comment: So it opens it in Safari, using iOS 12.2 on the simulator.

Comment: That is to be expected as there is no AppStore on the simulator. If you run the above code on a physical device it should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Aha! Ok. I will check and get back to you!

Comment: Seems the http links are now opening directly into the AppStore. Thanks!